# Why microsoft excel 2013 activex component can't create object?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue in running some Visual Basic Code in my 2013 Excel. I have a function, I and I am calling it in one of the excel columns. Here is my function as below :

```
Public Function GetDetailedDescriptionAsHtml(json As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If json = "" Then
        json = "[]"
    End If

    Set sc = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    Dim html As String

    sc.Eval "var obj=(" & json & ")" 'evaluate the json response
    sc.AddCode "function GetDetailedDescriptionHtml(){ var htm =''; for(var i = 0; i< obj.length; i++){ htm += '<h2>' + obj[i].Header + '</h2><p>' + obj[i].Description +'</p>' } return htm;}"

    html = sc.Run("GetDetailedDescriptionHtml")

    GetDetailedDescriptionAsHtml = html

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Something's wrong: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Function
```

The error message is saying : 'microsoft excel 2013 activex component can not create object' on this line of code 'Set sc = CreateObject("scriptcontrol")'.

The strange thing is this function is working on my colleagues except me.

WHy would be the reason for this ? Is there some specific libraries need to be referenced? I have searched over the web, but I could not resolve the issue till now.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Add this 'Dim sc As New ScriptControl' **edit** no that can't be it, gotta be a missing library if the exact code works elsewhere.

Comment: the exact code works in other excel machines. I am reinstalling it again and i will try your code once I am done. Thank for your answer.

Comment: @sten I tried your code, another error comes in, User-defined type not defined on this line 'Dim sc As New ScriptControl'

Comment: Then it's definitely the library. I don't know off the top of my head which one it is. Look at the other system and see what they have enabled.

Comment: Is your Office version 64-bit?  I think you'd need the 32-bit version for this.

Comment: @TimWilliams you are right, I did a test to run the VB code from the console using the 32-bit version and that code was executed with no error, however with the 64 it did not work and it generated the same error. Thanks for your help.